# Strange Big Query projects visible when coupling/linking GA4 to Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When linking my Google Analytics 4 property I came across a lot of strange Big Query projects which are not visbible in Google Big Query. Where can I find these projects in BQ?

The Project IDs all start with "sys-[several numbers]" and have the project name "CHATGPT" (see attachment). Should I be worried, because these projects do look quite shady, hence my question. If somebody could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7oJ0.jpg)